# truncate a Float in java 1.5 excluding setRoundingMode

Tags: java, format, java-5

I want to truncate a float value  in Java.

Following are my requirements:

> 1. if i have 12.49688f, it should be printed as 12.49 without rounding off
> 2. if it is 12.456 in double, it should be printed as 12.45 without rounding off
> 3. In any case if the value is like 12.0, it should be printed as 12 only.
>
> Condition 3 is to be always kept in mind.It should be concurrent with
>   truncating logic.

P.S: I am using Java 1.5 . So i know how to do it in Java 1.6 i.e using Decimal Format and calling `setroundingMode ()` Method.
I need to know for Java 1.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiply, use [Math#floor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#floor%28double%29) and divide before providing the number to the DecimalFormat. This is the same as cutoff roundig.

```
// Replace N with the desired number of decimals after the comma
number = Math.floor(1eN * number) / 1eN
```

This isn't perfect because of rounding errors in floating point calculation, so you will still have to specify N decimals to the DecimalFormat.

A (more expensive, but also more logical) alternative is to use a [BigDecimal](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).

```
// Given as seperate statements for clarity, but these can be combined into a single line
// Replace "N" with the number of decimals after the comma
MathContext NDecimals = new MathContext(N, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
BigDecimal bdNumber = new BigDecimal(number, NDecimals);
number = bdNumber.doubleValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to string and truncate anything after the second digit after the period.
trim "0" and "." if having an "."

```
String x = Double.toString (12.456); // or Float.toString (12.49688f);

int pos = x.indexOf ('.');  // 
if (pos >= 0) {
  int end = Math.min(pos + 2, x.length() - 1); // truncate after 2 digits
  while (x.charAt (end) == '0') end --;  // trim 0
  if (x.charAt (end) == '.') end --; // trim .
  x = x.substring(0, end + 1);       // really truncate
}
```

(tested, works in my environment)

Comment: @ stefan bachert If i enter 12.2 It should Give me 12.20 ?